# How to use OGNL expression in JSP / Struts2

Tags: struts2, expression, ognl

Like [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html), is it possible to use any [OGNL expressions](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html) outside of the [s: tags](https://struts.apache.org/docs/tag-reference.html) in regular HTML?

e.g., if I wanted to get the value of some bean in EL I would do something like  `<div>${beanName.propertyName}` within `DIV` blocks or something.

How can this be done using OGNL. I've got a code block:

```
    <s:iterator value="parentBean.qna" var="questionAndAnswers"
                status="qIndex">
      <li>
        <s:label theme="simple"
                 value="Question %{#qIndex.index+1} - %{#questionAndAnswers.question}"/>

        <ul>
        <s:iterator value="%{#questionAndAnswers.answers}" var="answer" status="answersStat">
        <li>            
        <input  type="radio" name="parentBean.answerMap['%{qIndex}']" />'
        value='<s:property value="%{#answersStat.index}"/>'><s:property value="%{#answer}" /></input>
        </li>
        </s:iterator>
        </ul>
        <br/>
      </li>
    </s:iterator>
```

Where it says `input type="radio" name="parentBean.answerMap['%{qIndex}']" ...` 
I want the value of `qIndex` to be replaced dynamically with the current index so that the value can be set to the corresponding key at the back. So, if it was `parentBean.answerMap[1]`, I'm assuming the map at the Action would have the `key=1` and value of the input.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using OGNL syntax, no; JSP doesn't know anything about OGNL.

S2's request wrapper *will* allow querying the value stack using JSP EL syntax (`${}`) but I don't believe that will extend to named values (values that aren't pushed on to the stack, like the iterator index).

Of course, you don't *need* to–use `<s:property value="#qIndex.index"/>` in your tag's attributes, just like you do for the `value` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I solved this last night. I decided to give EL a try within the Struts tags and it seemed to work. I thought it wouldn't but it did. So that makes life easier. Appreciate the explanation